# Error 1045 Windows 10 MySQL cannot log without a password

Tags: mysql

I have a server running locally and is showing in the Services as running.

However when I run `mysql -u root -p` I am getting an error

> Error 1045 Access denied.

Any idea how I remove the password so I can access the server?

Comment: when you installed the MySQL server it should have asked you to create a root password. Did that happen? So just use the password you created. If you didn't make a note of that password, well....then that was not the cleverest thing you will do this week :-)

Comment: I did but for some reason the password is not being accepted

Comment: well in the code above which you've shown us, you haven't typed any password. But if you did type one in reality (I assume it prompts you?), then presumably either a) you made a typo or b) the password isn't what you think it is. Clearly, we have no idea what password you really set. You should be able to connect using the code above and a correct password.